# What is the best / most elegant way for doing form validation and styling validation error messages in Angular 2 (Reactive Forms)?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, angular

I am creating a (relatively) simple form using Angular 2 reactive forms. The fields are simple: first name, last name, email, password, and post code. There are confirm fields for email and password. There are also some relatively simple validation rules, i.e. first name and last name must be longer than two characters, email must be a valid email address etc.

For the UI, I am using Bootstrap to style the form and add visual validation highlights, e.g. using has-error on divs for fields that did not validate. After adding it in, I find that the HTML is very cluttered and there must be a better way to simplify the form, e.g. using custom validators or custom form controls. I would appreciate if you could help me getting to the best way of developing the form and improving my Angular 2 skills (I am a beginner in this framework).

Template below:

```
<div class="well">
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="nameForm" [formGroup]="nameForm" (ngSubmit)="save(nameForm.value, nameForm.valid)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': !nameForm.controls.firstname.pristine && !nameForm.controls.firstname.valid }">
      <label for="firstname" class="control-label">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" formControlName="firstname"
        required minlength="2" />
      <span [hidden]="nameForm.controls.firstname.valid || (nameForm.controls.firstname.pristine && !submitted)" class="text-danger">
            First name is required (minimum 2 characters).
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': !nameForm.controls.lastname.pristine && !nameForm.controls.lastname.valid }">
      <label for="lastname" class="control-label">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" formControlName="lastname"
        required minlength="2" />
      <span [hidden]="nameForm.controls.lastname.valid || (nameForm.controls.lastname.pristine && !submitted)" class="text-danger">
            Last name is required (minimum 2 characters).
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': !nameForm.controls.email.pristine && !nameForm.controls.email.valid }">
      <label for="email" class="control-label">Your e-mail address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address" formControlName="email"
        required />
      <span [hidden]="nameForm.controls.email.valid || (nameForm.controls.email.pristine && !submitted)" class="text-danger">
            Valid e-mail address required
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': !nameForm.controls.emailrepeat.pristine && !nameForm.controls.emailrepeat.valid }">
      <label for="emailrepeat" class="control-label">Your e-mail address (repeat)</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailrepeat" placeholder="E-mail address again" formControlName="emailrepeat" required />
      <span [hidden]="(nameForm.controls.email.valid && nameForm.controls.emailrepeat.value == nameForm.controls.email.value) || (nameForm.controls.emailrepeat.pristine && !submitted)" class="error">
            E-mail addresses must match
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': !nameForm.controls.password.pristine && !nameForm.controls.password.valid }">
      <label for="passsword" class="control-label">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" formControlName="password"
       minlength="5" required />
      <span [hidden]="nameForm.controls.password.valid || (nameForm.controls.password.pristine && !submitted)" class="error">
            Password is required (minimum 5 characters)
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': !nameForm.controls.passwordrepeat.pristine && !nameForm.controls.passwordrepeat.valid }">
      <label for="repeatpasssword" class="control-label">Password (repeat)</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordrepeat" formControlName="passwordrepeat"
        required />
      <span [hidden]="(nameForm.controls.passwordrepeat.valid && nameForm.controls.passwordrepeat.value == nameForm.controls.password.value) || (nameForm.controls.passwordrepeat.pristine && !submitted)" class="error">
            Passwords must match
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="postcode" class="control-label">Postcode</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="postcode" placeholder="E.g. 2000" formControlName="postcode"
      />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="nameForm.invalid">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'enrol',
  templateUrl: './enrol.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enrol.component.css']
})
export class EnrolComponent implements OnInit {

  public member: Member; 
  public nameForm: FormGroup; 
  public submitted: boolean;
  public events: any[] = []; 

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const emailRegex = '^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$';
    // Initialise form here: 
    this.nameForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: [null, [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(2)]],
      lastname:  [null, [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(2)]],
      email:     [null, [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.pattern(emailRegex)]], 
      emailrepeat: [null, [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.pattern(emailRegex)]], 
      password:     [null, [<any>Validators.required]], 
      passwordrepeat: [null, [<any>Validators.required]], 
      postcode: null
    })
  }

  save (model: Member, isValid: boolean) { 
    this.submitted = true;
    // check if model is valid
    // if valid, call API to save it
    console.log(model, isValid);
  }

}

export interface Member { 
  firstname: string; 
  lastname: string; 
  password: string; 
  passwordrepeat: string;
  email: string; 
  emailrepeat: string; 
  postcode?: number;
}
```

PS - comments on code style etc are also much welcome. I am a back-end developer by trade and not that wellversed in front-end development.